# CygWin: apt-file alternative?

Tags: cygwin

I am installing `yt-dlp` from source. It requires `pandoc`, which I believe is available in a CygWin package.

On Ubuntu I would run:

```
apt-file search /pandoc
```

to identify which package to install.

What is the CygWin equivalent for `apt-file`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool is cygcheck

```
$ cygcheck -p pandoc
Found 13 matches for pandoc
....
```

Or you can use the search at
https://cygwin.com/packages/

but the results give no indications that a `pandoc` program is available
in any Cygwin packages.
See details on:
https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=pandoc&arch=x86_64

```
$ cygcheck -p bin/pandoc
Found 0 matches for bin/pandoc
```

Comment: from the website https://github.com/jgm/pandoc, it comes that `Pandoc` is a `Haskell` program and `Haskell` in not available in Cygwin